# Symfony4 MakerBundle Own Crud Maker

Tags: crud, symfony4, boilerplate

I want to customize the boilerplate code of the new makerbundle crud maker. There is no simple overwriting the templates as it was in SensioGeneratorBundle. I tried to generate a custom MyMakeCrud based on the original code - but i struggle about the injected DoctrineEntityHelper $entityHelper.

```
 Cannot autowire service "App\Maker\MakeMyCrud": argument "$entityHelper" of
 method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Doctri
 ne\DoctrineEntityHelper" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias
 this class to the existing "maker.doctrine_entity_helper" service.
```

The existing maker.doctrine_entity_helper is defined private in the maker bundle. How can i get the injection to run?

Could you help me? Has anyone an example for customizing the crud generation? New in sf4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a service for it like below:

```
    app.maker.make_crud:
    class: App\Maker\MakeCrud
    arguments: ['@maker.doctrine_helper']
    calls:
        - [configureCommand, ['@security.command.user_password_encoder', '@?']]
        - [interact, ['@?', '@?', '@security.command.user_password_encoder']]
    tags:
        - { name: maker.command }
```

I placed this in `config/services.yaml`.

`App\Maker\MakeCrud` is your crud maker class.

Should really place this in a services_dev.yaml file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this (in config/services.yaml - with App\Maker\MakeMyCrud). Get: The service "maker.auto_command.make_my_crud" has a dependency on a non-existent service "maker.doctrine_helper" ?

Comment: Only an argument mistake: @maker.doctrine_entity_helper - then it is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to both of you for this post. I had to customize the MakeCrud command too.
This is the configuration which worked for me for version 5.

```
app.maker.make_crud:
    class: App\Maker\MakeCrudCommand
    arguments: ['@maker.doctrine_helper', '@maker.renderer.form_type_renderer']
    calls:
        - [configureCommand, ['@security.command.user_password_encoder', '@?']]
        - [interact, ['@?', '@?', '@security.command.user_password_encoder']]
    tags:
        - { name: maker.command }
```

Comment: Given this, I take it that @Carl-Owens' answer no longer works in version 5?