# How to customize The Symfony MakerBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to customize the *maker:crud*.

The official documentation and [The Symfony MakerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) indicates "*you can create your own make: ... command reusing the tools provided by this bundle .To do that, you should create a class that extends AbstractMaker in your src/Maker/ directory*".

So my first step is to copy from the repository, which is also indicated in the documentation, the script *[MakeCrud.php](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Maker/MakeCrud.php)* in the *src/Maker/MakeCustomCrud.php* (I rename it). I apply some basic changes like renaming the class and the name of the command.

When ready the available commands I am waiting to see between the commands make some *make:custom-crud*. Obviously when trying to invoke it (*php bin/console make:custom-crud*) I am informed ***Command "make:custom-crud" is not defined.***  I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what it is.

I transcribe part of the code below *src/Maker/MakeCustomCrud.php*:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony MakerBundle package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Maker;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle;
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\ConsoleStyle;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\DependencyBuilder;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Doctrine\DoctrineHelper;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Generator;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\InputConfiguration;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Renderer\FormTypeRenderer;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Str;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Validator;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

/**
 * @author Sadicov Vladimir <sadikoff@gmail.com>
 */
final class MakeCustomCrud extends AbstractMaker
{
    private $doctrineHelper;

    private $formTypeRenderer;

    public function __construct(DoctrineHelper $doctrineHelper, FormTypeRenderer $formTypeRenderer)
    {
        $this->doctrineHelper = $doctrineHelper;
        $this->formTypeRenderer = $formTypeRenderer;
    }

    public static function getCommandName(): string
    {
        return 'make:custom-crud';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureCommand(Command $command, InputConfiguration $inputConfig)
    {
        $command
            ->setDescription('Creates Custom CRUD for Doctrine entity class')
            ->addArgument('entity-class', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, sprintf('The class name of the entity to create Custom CRUD (e.g. <fg=yellow>%s</>)', Str::asClassName(Str::getRandomTerm())))
            ->setHelp(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../Resources/help/MakeCrud.txt'))
        ;

        $inputConfig->setArgumentAsNonInteractive('entity-class');
    }
```

Comment: When I replace the namespace with `App\Maker` I must add a `use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Maker\AbstractMaker` but Symfony reports _Cannot autowire service "App\Maker\MakeCustomCrud": argument "$doctrineHelper" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Doctrine\DoctrineHelper" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "maker.doctrine_helper" service._

Comment: I can solve the error with the solution offered in [Symfony4 MakerBundle Own Crud Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273223/symfony4-makerbundle-own-crud-maker) but the constructor has a second argument of type `FormTypeRenderer` on which I cannot resolve.

Also, I feel that the path does not go through configuring sevices.yaml. I feel it should be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch it with composer:

- Make a directory `./patch`
- Copy the file of vendor directory `./vendor/symfony/maker--bundle/src/Resources/skeleton/form/Type.tpl.php`
  and add in your `composer.json`

Example:

```
 "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "patch": [
        "cp patch/patch_crud/Type.tpl.php vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Resources/skeleton/form/."
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        [
            "@patch",
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@patch",
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
```

you can modify the file

a example of this [here](https://github.com/eldinomick/patch_crud)

Comment: I did not notice that the answer to my question had been answered long ago. I want to thank @Cadot.eu for doing it.

I recently had a chance to put what they suggested into practice and it worked wonders. I have been able to do a lot of CRUDs with symfony which have saved me a lot of time. Symfony's default CRUDs are workable but rather simple UI-wise. I have been able to adapt the generation to do it with Bootstrap 5 and [Omines/Datatables](https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle). A beauty.

Comment: It only remains to comment that for Windows-based development environments, I had to install [slowprog/composer-copy-file](https://packagist.org/packages/slowprog/composer-copy-file).

Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem with this lines in services.yaml

```
maker.renderer.form_type_renderer:
    class: Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Renderer\FormTypeRenderer
    arguments:
         - '@maker.generator'
Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Renderer\FormTypeRenderer:
    alias: maker.renderer.form_type_renderer
```

I hope it helps you